# jquery 1.6.1 ruins background in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opera

I just set up the Nivo Slider. At the first try everything was ok.

But after several refreshes I noticed that background of html body ruins.

it makes 20px "white margin" from above, and for the bottom too. It "cuts" the background. I opened the same page in IE8, FireFox, Chrome, Safari - everything looks great.

When I turn on the Outline in Opera, everything fixes, when I turn off the outline and then refresh it breaks again.

I disabled the css of Nivoslider, though some css was breaking my design, but everything was bad. and then disables jquery 1.6.1 and it fixed.

Why should something like that happen? any conflict?

Comment: `html,body{margin:0; padding:0;}` I think this could help... worth a try

Comment: @Val thanks, for reply, I always to do that :)

Comment: Can you paste your code and reproduce this in http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

You might try JQuery 1.6.4.  The 1.6 series of JQuery had multiple small bug fixes.  1.6.4 is probably going to be the last in the series.  Most likely it won't fix your problem, but it's worth a try.